# How do I find out if I’m in the middle of a histedit with mercurial?

Tags: git, mercurial, rebase

Some mercurial/git commands drop you on the command line if they require your intervention (or if you requested intervention).

With mercurial, how do I find out if I am in the middle of a `hg rebase` or `hg histedit`? With git a `git status` reminds you of the current situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `hg summary` should list any outstanding rebase or histedit operations.